# new SonarQube Java profile - no way to provide PDM Checkstyle or Findbugs XML

Tags: sonarqube

new to SonarQube..

My SonarQube server is 5.2.1 on RHEL 6.  I'm guessing this is a community edition since I installed a native package from http : // sonar-pkg.sourceforge.net/

I'm following sonarcube.org [article](http://www.sonarqube.org/screencasts2/configuring-coding-rules/) on configuring coding rules.  According to it, I should be able to
- create a new Quality Profile
- select Language (e.g. Java)
- and optionally provide PDM XML, Checkstyle XML and Findbugs XML.

With my instance of SonarQube server, I see a "+Create" link opposite from "Java Profiles", (I have no option to even select a non-Java profile) and the only option I have for this new Java profile is to provide a name.  That's it.  Is the ability to create and configure a Java profile unavailable in the Community edition?

Also, I'm not able to update the Java plugin - I get error message:

> Fail to download the plugin (java, version 3.5) from https ://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-java-plugin/sonar-java-plugin-3.5.jar (error is : Fail to download: https ://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-java-plugin/sonar-java-plugin-3.5.jar (no proxy))

even though my proxy is configured correctly as the Update Center is able to check for system udpates:

> System is up to date.
>   Updated on Sat Aug 29 16:29:24 PDT 2015. Refresh

Anyone has any idea why my SonarQube server software seems to lack these capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding inability to download plugins .. 
Turns out, it is not a proxy issue.

As of right now, there must be some issue in the SonarQube software with downloading sonar-java-plugin-3.5.jar, or with how it is hosted on sonarsource.bintray.com

I've downloaded the jar manually by placing it in extensions/plugins.  After this, I had no trouble at all installing/updating checkstyle, findbugs, etc., plugins.

To answer the original question: once the corresponding plugins are installed, the new Quality Profile dialog will provide a way to optionally upload the corresponding XML configs.

Answer (score 0):

By default, PMD and Checkstyle plugins are not installed in a fresh SonarQube instance, that's why it was not possible for you to create a quality profile from PMD or Checkstyle XML files.